# Pass arguments from command line as a list and parse it

Tags: python, parameter-passing, argparse

I have following code:

```
import arg
parser = arg.ArgumentParser(description="<%=@project_name%> Command Line.")
parser.add_argument(
        "--inputs", "-i", help="input files.", default="./",
    )
parser.add_argument(
        "--controls", "-c", help="Parms.", default=False
    )
parser.add_argument(
        "--outputs", "-o", help="output files.", default="./"
    )
```

and I run the code simply as

```
python code.py -i ./ -o ./
```

just wondering how can I pass a list of parameters as argument and parse through it in python? Something like:

```
python code.py -i ./ -o ./ -c [False, 5, 'aStr']
```

Comment: Shouldn't `import arg` be `import argparse`?

Comment: You could pass a comma separated list of values. For example "python code.py a b c d,e,f" and then `sys.argv[4].split(",")`

Comment: Look at `sys.argv` so you understand how those strings are split by the shell.  You may need more quoting.  The parser works from `argv`.

Comment: How about accepting `"python code.py -i ./ -o ./ -c False 5 aStr"`.  The '[' and ',' make parsing harder.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the argument on the command line:

```
python code.py -i ./ -o ./ -c "[False, 5, 'aStr']"
```

Then use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse its value.

```
import ast
...
controls = ast.literal_eval(parser.controls)
```